# What is missing in todays patents search engines?

Tags: search, patent-search

The patents search engines market is saturated with big players, there are many engines, each offers more or the same features.

How would you describe the best patents search engine? what would you like to have in such a search engine? beside of-course, the search option.

how do you chose your search engine?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, the user interface wherein one can easily access the claims, summary and drawings related to the patents get the highest priority.

Also, the engines which give clear and easy access to classifications of the patent i.e. the US classification, the ECLA and the CPC classification are preferred.

Thirdly, a search engine which accesses patents worldwide especially the chinese patents add up to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Comprehensiveness in coverage. Ability to include English machine translations of non-English specifications and claims in a search (not just abstract). Search results ranked by relevance. Easy hyperlinks to forward and backward citations. Automatically store a large number of search query histories. Proximity criteria in searching. Folders for saved documents. Legal Status. Family members. Related Court cases. Private annotation. Reporting that includes high-res thumbnails of figures. Maybe automatically find other things that are similar to: X, Y and Z documents.